# Magento 2.x Theme Configuring page is loading infinity

Tags: theme, magento-2.2.5

I need help to solve the issue from maganto 2.x **theme** configuring. I was trying to Add my contents into my Theme Like, `Header`, `Footer` etc. but the theme page is loading infinity. Please check my screenshot below.
[image]

> Location: Content-->Configuration-->Themes

When I am trying to edit the theme the theme configure page is loading infinity.

I need help to resolve it. Please tell me the way to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: usually this can be done by refreshing the page, it's happening because if you look in your console, some resources have failed to load. This might not be the case you have but my advice is to keep refreshing until it all loads. Let me know if this does not work for you (more than 4 times)

Comment: I was trying since last week to resolve it but thing is that, it's happening everyday and I couldn't work on this location.

Comment: have a look in your JS console, do you get a lot of errors?

Comment: No I didn't any error except this issue